# git remote and origin <url> not working. error raised as unknown subcommand

Tags: git, github, github-actions

can anyone please guide me with these git commands. I've followed the steps from the github site to push the code. but i'm getting this error.

***note: there is no error in url***

**git remote and origin https://github.com/Goutham10/MatchGame.git**

error: Unknown subcommand: and

usage: git remote [-v | --verbose]
or: git remote add [-t ] [-m ] [-f] [--tags | --no-tags] [--mirror=<fetch|push>]

```
  -v, --verbose         be verbose; must be placed before a subcommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your subcommand

`git remote add origin <url>`